# Cannot invoke "String.replaceAll(String, String)" because row is null

Tags: talend

I am getting an error message in Talend and it appears to be down to a  having a 'NULL' value within my 'comments' field.

I currently have this expression row1.comments.replaceAll("\u0000", "") which has been working and the reason for having this in place is because I have some text which is spaced out (example T E S T).

However,the latest run has failed due to a 'NULL' appearing in the comments field and I don't think my job design knows how to handle this, as well as the removing the spaces from the 'comments' text.

This is the error message:
Exception in component tMap_1 (FACT_test)

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.replaceAll(String, String)" because "row1.comments" is null

Is there anyway to get around this problem, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a little bit of information missing from your question (like what component are you using?) but regardless, you can check for `null` and deal with it accordingly using a ternary operator, something like this should work ...

```
row1.comments == null ? "" : row1.comments.replaceAll("\u0000", "")
```

Comment: I am using tMap. Your suggestion has worked perfectly, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Kinda figured but couldn’t be sure. Glad I could help.